# How to find remaining alphabets?

Tags: sql-server

I have one table and i want to write query to fetch data

```
empno empname 
  1     abc
  2     xyz
  3     mnc
  4     pqr
```

Now i want to write query those alphabets which is not used in `empname` as first letter like

> b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,n,o,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,y,z

I don't need that alphabets which is used in first letter of `empname`

> a,x,m,p

so how can i write query for this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bellow query

```
select * from employee
  where empname not like 'a%' 
    and empname not like 'x%' 
    and empname not like 'm%' 
    and empname not like 'p%'
```

> here 's%' use for select first character of the name.

Comment: How do you come to know only these 4 characters are there in  the first letter of `empname`?

Answer (score 2):

First just use a table variable to store all the alphabets like below.

```
declare @alphabets as table(letter varchar(1));

insert into @alphabets values
('a'),
('b'),
('c'),
('d'),
('e'),
('f'),
('g'),
('h'),
('i'),
('j'),
('k'),
('l'),
('m'),
('n'),
('o'),
('p'),
('q'),
('r'),
('s'),
('t'),
('u'),
('v'),
('w'),
('x'),
('y'),
('z');
```

Then use `NOT EXISTS` to find the missing alphabets from the table variable with the first character of `empname` and use `STUFF` to concatenate all with comma.

**Query**

```
select stuff((select ', ' + t.letter from(
    select * from @alphabets a
    where not exists(
        select 1 from [your_table_name] e
        where a.letter = left(e.empname, 1)
    )
)t
for xml path('')
), 1, 2, '');
```

### **[`Demo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/597178/how-to-find-remaining-alphabets)**

Comment: i checked your query but its not worked could you please explain me ?

Comment: Why it is not working? Run the query along with the table variable `@alphabets`. Check the demo link which is there in my answer. Also change `[your_table_name]` with your actual table name.